# invisible border cuts FloatingActionButton layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

**Problem:** I have a FloatingActionButton with a progress indicator. But when the progress indicator is showing progress its layout seems to be cut at the edges of the invisible layout box:

[image]

Question: How can I remove that cutting layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/maschinelistcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle
        android:id="@+id/fabProgressCircle_download_maschinen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_download_maschinen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add padding to `RelativeLayout` as well.

Comment: @vrundpurohit Can you explain it more clearly, please? I do not have a RelativeLayout in my xml

Comment: i meant wrap your `FABProgressCircle` in one `RelativeLayout` and add padding to that layout.

Comment: I have set: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:padding="10dp"
        > and it unfortunately does not work

Comment: Did you solved your problem? Same is happening here. But only for some devices!!!